# bash - command not found

Tags: bash

I have a script

```
[pic@pic Desktop]$ cat skrypt.sh 
#!/bin/bash

awk '{sub(/#echo "Wstałem"/,"#echo \"Wstałem\""); print $0 > "skrypt.sh"}' skrypt.sh
awk '{sub(/awk/,"#awk"); print $0 > "skrypt.sh"}' skrypt.sh

[pic@pic Desktop]$
```

I run the script

```
[pic@pic Desktop]$ ./skrypt.sh 
./skrypt.sh: line 5: h: command not found
[pic@pic Desktop]$
```

Why gets the message?

```
./skrypt.sh: line 5: h: command not found
```

**EDIT:**

After running the script I want to get the result

```
#!/bin/bash

#awk '{sub(/#echo "Wstałem"/,"#echo \"Wstałem\""); print $0 > "skrypt.sh"}' skrypt.sh
#awk '{sub(/awk/,"#awk"); print $0 > "skrypt.sh"}' skrypt.sh
```

This is just an example. The idea is that in a real script after the call has been commented out the line above.

Comment: Did you try to append the script path?

Comment: Your script looks very strange. Can you explain what you suppose to do?

Comment: You cannot modify script while executing it, and with `>` redirection you basically delete all lines from script and only then add some other stuff. It is not clear for me what are you **really** trying to do.

Comment: Seems due to the two awk lines, operating on the script itself, a stray `h` character somehow ends up in the script which gets executed resulting in the error message.

Comment: Why you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is just an example. The idea is that in a real script after the call has been commented out the line above. See my edit.

Comment: @nowy1 The script should comment out all lines in itself? I think your question fits perfectly in [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strace behaviour. But there is a logic behind.

`bash` reads the script line by line. The first `awk` statement just writes the `skrypt.sh` file new, with the same content, because there is nothing to replace.

The second `awk` statement replaces `awk` with `#awk` (single substitution). So, it **adds** one character. Then `bash` reads the rest of the file. The offset is positioned at the end of the line (with the second `awk` statement, line 4). But that line is now a bit longer (one character). So bash reads the rest of the line, which is a single `h`. That is threaded as a command (because we are in a `bash` script and it ends with a newline). And `h`, of course, is not a valid command, hence the error message.

To accomplish what you want (apart from that your script is very precarious) add a character more at the end of line 4, which cannot be interpreted as a command, a space () for example.

**Last, but not least:**

> You shall not edit a scripts within itself.